# Python - Options for accessing class attributes/methods from other classes while keeping classes encapsulated?

Tags: python, oop, encapsulation

I'm teaching myself python and am working on a space invaders clone. Pretty much everything is working as I want it to. But I'm also trying to teach myself good principles of object-oriented design.

I have one class AlienInvasion that initializes a bunch of game objects and runs the while loop for the game (it currently also does some other things that should probably be in their own classes). When I create each object I pass it the AlienInvasion object so that each class can get access to objects that it needs to interact with. For example here is a class that checks for and responds to events:

```
import sys

import pygame


class EventHandler:

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize attributes."""
        self.ai_game = ai_game
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.display = ai_game.display
        self.stats = ai_game.stats
        self.sb = ai_game.sb
        self.ship = ai_game.ship

    def check_events(self):
        """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.sb.record_high_score()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                self._check_button(mouse_pos)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        """Respond to keypresses."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            self.ai_game.quit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self.ship.fire_bullet()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_e and not self.stats.game_active:
            self.settings.set_difficulty(self.settings.easy)
            self.ai_game.start_game()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_n and not self.stats.game_active:
            self.settings.set_difficulty(self.settings.normal)
            self.ai_game.start_game()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_h and not self.stats.game_active:
            self.settings.set_difficulty(self.settings.hard)
            self.ai_game.start_game()

    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        """Respond to key releases."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = False

    def _check_button(self, mouse_pos):
        """Set the difficulty setting."""
        if self.display.easy_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.settings.set_difficulty(self.settings.easy)
            self.ai_game.start_game()
        elif self.display.normal_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.settings.set_difficulty(self.settings.normal)
            self.ai_game.start_game()
        elif self.display.hard_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.settings.set_difficulty(self.settings.hard)
            self.ai_game.start_game()
        elif self.display.quit_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.ai_game.quit()
```

The initialization method consists entirely of setting up attributes referencing objects from ai_game (the AlienInvasion class) so that EventHandler can tell each object when it needs to do in response to an event. This is how I've been handling all object interactions. The AlienInvasion class 'knows' about all the different objects and allows each object to interact with other objects via the sorts of attributes you see above in the EventHandler.

I'm interested in learning how to make my code more maintainable. I've spent the last few days looking for an answer. I haven't seen anything that explains how I should be handling object interactions (or, more accurately, I haven't seen anything that I recognized as something I could/should apply here to minimize how much each object 'knows' about the other objects).

You can see the full code at https://github.com/nmoore32/Space-Invaders-Clone

Comment: This question is too broad. General "best practice" question invite opinion-based answers, you should ask specific questions that can have objectively correct answers.

Comment: If you're looking for advice on general principles of software design, [softwareengineering.se] is a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I'll ask in Software Engineering then.